# Customplaceholder has no matching function to call QT label

Tags: c++, qt, placeholder

I have a problem regarding my QT project. I want to create a touchable Qlabel, so I created a placeholder in the gui designer and referenced it to my "watchlistlabel" which extends from QLabel. When I now start my app I get the error " no matching function for call to WatchListLabel::WatchListLabel(QGroupBox*&)'
name1 = new WatchListLabel(groupBox_3);

My labels are in a groupbox does this affect my code?
why it cant find a matching function?
                                              ^

```
 #include<QLabel>

  class WatchListLabel: public QLabel
{
   Q_OBJECT
  private: 
     void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event) override;
 public:
    WatchListLabel();
 };
```

watchlistlabel.cpp

```
  #include "watchlistlabel.h"

 void WatchListLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {



    }

  WatchListLabel::WatchListLabel()
 {

 }
```

[QTdesigner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMNu4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a constructor which takes parent widget. General advice against this is to create new QObject subclasses using Qt Creator new class wizard, it will get everything right. But to solve the problem with this class, try replacing your default constructor with this constructor:

Declaration in .h:

```
explicit WatchListLabel(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
```

Definition in .cpp:

```
WatchListLabel::WatchListLabel(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel(parent) 
    //, any other member variable initializations
{
    // any constructor code if needed
}
```